# DevExpress XtraGrid Formatting - how to enclose all negative numbers in parenthesis

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid, number-formatting, negative-number

I am using [DevExpress XtraGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/) to show data. I would like to show the negative numbers in parenthesis. Numbers include both positive and negative numbers.

Eg:

```
123.448
-234.887
-35687.98753
87654.98765
```

etc...

I want to format them as below

```
123.448
(234.887)
(35,687.98753)
87,654.98765
```

What would be the format string that needs to be used, to get the above result?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the custom [numeric mask](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1498) on your column editor:

```
this.gridColumn1.ColumnEdit = this.repositoryItemTextEdit1;
//...
this.repositoryItemTextEdit1.Mask.EditMask = "###,###,###,##0.0##;(###,###,###,##0.0##)";
this.repositoryItemTextEdit1.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.Numeric;
this.repositoryItemTextEdit1.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the GridView.CustomColumnDisplayText event to change the way the data looks. Using a Mask is much neater though.

Answer (score 0):

```
settings.Columns.Add(set =>
                    {
                        set.FieldName = "myField";
                        set.Caption = "myFieldCaption";
                        set.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.String;
                        set.UnboundExpression = "Iif([myField] < 0, '(' +[myField]+ ')', [myField])";
                    });
```

It is done like this in mvc but I don't know how it is done in winforms.